# How to run Jmeter remotely on multiple slaves to stress multiple servers

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I have a requirement wherein I need to run different jmeter testplans on different target servers. I went through this PDF [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf), but it does not meet my requirements. It explains how to stress a "single" webserver from different slaves using single jmeter master. But my requirement is to stress different servers from different slaves using single jmeter master. One way I could find is like below

- Open multiple jmeter GUI instances on the jmeter master.
- Create different testplans in each jmeter instance (basically these testplans differ only in terms of target server and login information)
- Go to Run -> Remote Start -> Choose different slave in each instance

But I don't like this myself. Is there any better way to achieve this..?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it`s a best way, some workaround:

1. Start the jmeter servers with some parameter :

   SERVER_PORT=44444 ./jmeter-server -**Jparam**=1 &

   SERVER_PORT=44445 ./jmeter-server -**Jparam**=2 &

   SERVER_PORT=44446 ./jmeter-server -**Jparam**=3 &
2. Add this parameter in your testplan (in user defined variables):
   [image]
3. And in testplan add a thread group and inside of this thread group a several **If controllers** with conditions like a **${__javaScript(${param}==1)}**. Inside these If controllers put your different testplans:
   [image]

Theriotically, they will start to work with different "branches". Also you can change the number of users depends of this parameter by using Beanshell and to use different pools for user names/password using **CSV controller**. ( /home/pools/${param}/pool.csv)